# Calling JavaScript Azure Function as an Activity function in a .Net Core Function Orchestrator

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm quite new to azure functions and been trying out converting some legacy functionality in a desktop app to azure functions.

One of them is an email system. It includes a templating engine to generate emails and send those generated emails using send grid. I have now rewritten part of the templating engine as a proof of concept as a JavaScript azure function which uses MJML and handlebars.

There's a news broadcast that goes out every week and this takes data from multiple data sources (news stories, press releases etc.) and I was thinking that this would be a good fit for a durable function and make use of the same templating engine I've mentioned above.

Can I use this JavaScript function as an Activity function in a .Net Core Durable function?

Any guidance much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Core Functions i.e. Function 2.x requires single language in one Function app, which means you have to put JS function in another app and follow [cross-function-app-communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-types-features-overview#cross-function-app-communication).

Therefore the process could be following steps. A timer starts C# orchestator function, orchestator calls C# activity function which sends http request to start JS orchestator function, then JS orchestrator calls JS activity function to execute email work and send results back.

Comment: I was reading the documentation in detail today and came across the requirement for functions to use the same language in the same functions app. Thanks for the link, I'll give it a try.